I'm trying to import this library called plotly.express but getting an error
I'm trying to import this library called plotly.express but getting an error but cannot understand the error at all.
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

Error:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[19], line 2
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 import plotly.express as px
      3 import matplotlib
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plotly/express/__init__.py:14
      8 if pd is None:
      9     raise ImportError(
     10         """\
     11 Plotly express requires pandas to be installed."""
     12     )
---> 14 from ._imshow import imshow
     15 from ._chart_types import (  # noqa: F401
     16     scatter,
     17     scatter_3d,
   (...)
     50     density_mapbox,
     51 )
     54 from ._core import (  # noqa: F401
     55     set_mapbox_access_token,
     56     defaults,
     57     get_trendline_results,
     58     NO_COLOR,
     59 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plotly/express/_imshow.py:11
      8 from plotly.utils import image_array_to_data_uri
     10 try:
---> 11     import xarray
     13     xarray_imported = True
     14 except ImportError:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/__init__.py:3
      1 from importlib.metadata import version as _version
----> 3 from xarray import testing, tutorial
      4 from xarray.backends.api import (
      5     load_dataarray,
      6     load_dataset,
   (...)
     10     save_mfdataset,
     11 )
     12 from xarray.backends.zarr import open_zarr

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/testing/__init__.py:2
      1 # TODO: Add assert_isomorphic when making DataTree API public
----> 2 from xarray.testing.assertions import (  # noqa: F401
      3     _assert_dataarray_invariants,
      4     _assert_dataset_invariants,
      5     _assert_indexes_invariants_checks,
      6     _assert_internal_invariants,
      7     _assert_variable_invariants,
      8     _data_allclose_or_equiv,
      9     assert_allclose,
     10     assert_chunks_equal,
     11     assert_duckarray_allclose,
     12     assert_duckarray_equal,
     13     assert_equal,
     14     assert_identical,
     15 )
     17 __all__ = [
     18     "assert_allclose",
     19     "assert_chunks_equal",
   (...)
     23     "assert_identical",
     24 ]

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/testing/assertions.py:11
      8 import numpy as np
      9 import pandas as pd
---> 11 from xarray.core import duck_array_ops, formatting, utils
     12 from xarray.core.coordinates import Coordinates
     13 from xarray.core.dataarray import DataArray

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/core/duck_array_ops.py:37
     34 from packaging.version import Version
     35 from pandas.api.types import is_extension_array_dtype
---> 37 from xarray.core import dask_array_ops, dtypes, nputils
     38 from xarray.core.options import OPTIONS
     39 from xarray.core.utils import is_duck_array, is_duck_dask_array, module_available

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/core/dask_array_ops.py:3
      1 from __future__ import annotations
----> 3 from xarray.core import dtypes, nputils
      6 def dask_rolling_wrapper(moving_func, a, window, min_count=None, axis=-1):
      7     """Wrapper to apply bottleneck moving window funcs on dask arrays"""

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/core/nputils.py:14
     11 from xarray.namedarray import pycompat
     13 # remove once numpy 2.0 is the oldest supported version
---> 14 if module_available("numpy", minversion="2.0.0.dev0"):
     15     from numpy.lib.array_utils import (  # type: ignore[import-not-found,unused-ignore]
     16         normalize_axis_index,
     17     )
     18 else:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/namedarray/utils.py:62, in module_available(module, minversion)
     59 if minversion is not None:
     60     version = importlib.metadata.version(module)
---> 62     return Version(version) >= Version(minversion)
     64 return True

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/packaging/version.py:264, in Version.__init__(self, version)
    261 def __init__(self, version: str) -> None:
    262 
    263     # Validate the version and parse it into pieces
--> 264     match = self._regex.search(version)
    265     if not match:
    266         raise InvalidVersion(f"Invalid version: '{version}'")

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

For more background I was trying to learn ML with help of this
notebook:
I was following the instructions mentioned in the notebook and in the video. It's working for them but not for me. It's throwing an error as mentioned above.

Which versions of plotly and xarray do you have? How exactly did you install them? Your question needs to contain all the necessary information within the question itself (not in comments, behind external links, or in images or videos) and ideally nothing else. See also the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].
